# How to make clearfix work with overflow auto

Tags: css

I am creating a responsive layout using bootstrap. Layout has three rows. Top row has two columns and they stack vertically in small screens. The right column on top row has more information and hence height is more than the left one.

In desktop resolutions i have hidden the content of the right column using `overlfow:hidden` property. However in phone resolution i don't want this content to be hidden since the columns are stacked vertically. To achieve i am setting overflow to hidden using a media query.

Where i am stuck currently is, if i don't have `overflow:hidden` for the right column in top row `clearfix doesn't work and the contents of the right column overlaps the second row.

Wondering what i am doing wrong.`

Please find the jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/uyxgo70k/2/

Update:

I followed @DigitalDouble advice and made the prototype working. However when i keep the image and content inside a carousel item, height:auto doesn't work. Not sure which property inside the carousel classes are preventing the height:auto to take effect.

I have updated the jsfiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/uyxgo70k/7/

Comment: the carousel-inner class was setting overflow:hidden so i had to overwrite that to visible in my css. Fixed it. Updated the jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/uyxgo70k/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not `clearfix`. The problem is this:

```
div.row div {
    height: 100%;
    ...
}

div#top div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

You're giving your container a "fixed" height. So the content overflows out of the container and hovers over the next row unless you use `overflow: hidden`

A quick fix would be to add `height: auto` to your `#div-desc` on mobile devices using media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    #top #div-desc {
       height: auto;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uyxgo70k/6/

Answer (score 0):

You've set fixed heights so div's will overlap each other, because their layout-sizes are smaller then their content.

You should set the heights to auto or leave then unset.
Does this help you in the direction you want?
https://jsfiddle.net/gmbxgjub/

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  #div-desc{
      height: 100%;
      overflow:hidden;
  }
  #top{
    height: 40%;
  }

  div#top div{
    height: 100%;
  }

  #top.div img{
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

I've moved the height definitions into the media-query

Comment: Thanks Norbert, the images i display in both the columns will have different heights. I want to make all of them same height and hence had to set the parent's height.Didn't want to set an absolute height for the images.

Comment: Thank you Norbert  , @DigitalDouble answer did help me